# Backup Throwing 500 Error but no errors logged

Tags: drupal

Recently my backups started failing with "Internal Server Error". I checked the Apache error logs as well as Drupal's logs and I'm not seeing any errors. I've tried all of the combinations of backup including Download, Manual Backups Directory, etc. but all fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens only when your database is too large. Actually what is happening when you are trying to take Database backup it uses maximum of memory(RAM). SO it is a memory related issue. when you run backup check you RAM status it is using max of it and while trying to backup database aand all the things. Increase your RAM and PHP configuration. This issue will be resolved.

Hope it will help you.